# Adding entites to spacy doc object using BERT's offsets

Tags: python, data-science, spacy, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

Is there any way to add entities to a spacy doc object using BERT's offsets ? Problem is my whole pipeline is spacy dependent and i am using the latest PUBMEDBERT for which spacy doesnt provide support.

So at times  the offsets of entities given by pubmedbert dont result into a valid SPAN for spacy as the tokenization is completely different.

what work have i done till now to solve my problem ?
I made a custom tokenizer by asking spacy to split on punctuation, similar to bert but there are certain cases wherein i just cant make a rule. for example:-

```
text = '''assessment
Exdtve age-rel mclr degn, left eye, with actv chrdl neovas
Mar-10-2020
assessment'''
```

Pubmedbert predicted 13:17 to be an entity i.e. dtve
but on adding the span as entity in spacy doc object it results NONE as it is not a valid span.

```
span = doc.char_span(row['start'], row['end'], row['ent'])
doc.ents = list(doc.ents) + [span]
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Consider row['start'] to be 13, row['end'] to be 17 and row['ent'] to be label

how can i solve this problem ? is there anyway i can just add entities in spacy doc object using starting and ending offset given by pubmedbert

would really appreciate any help on this, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because spacy stores entities internally as IOB tags on tokens in the doc, you can only add entity spans that correspond to full tokens underneath.

If you're only using this `doc` to store these entities (not using any other components like a tagger or parser from another model that expect a different tokenizer), you can create a doc with the same tokenization as the BERT model:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
# bert_tokens = [..., "Ex", "dtve", ...]
words, spaces = spacy.util.get_words_and_spaces(bert_tokens, text)
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=words, spaces=spaces)
```

Then you should be able to add the entity spans to the document.

If you need the original spacy tokenization + entities based on a different tokenization, then you'll have to adjust the entity character offsets to match the spacy token boundaries in order to add them. Since this can depend a lot on the data/task (if `dtve` is an entity, is `Exdtve` also necessarily an entity of the same type?), you probably need a custom solution based on your data. If you're trying to adjust the entity spans to line up with the current tokens, you can see the character start and length for each token with `token.idx` and `len(token)`.

Comment: Another way is to modify spacy's  tokenizer to character wise and then add whatever you want as spans :D